# Learning Selenium, Python. Problem with Page object

Tags: python, selenium, pageobjects

I'm currently reading through the docs for selenium. This part [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html) has me a bit confused. Perticuallary the part of the base page. It is described as follows:

```
class BasePage(object):
    """Base class to initialize the base page that will be called from all pages"""

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
```

But if this is suppost to be the parent for all classes. should it not be the responsibility of this class to instantiate the driver and wrap the methods of the driver into more suitable code? What i mean is this:

```
class BasePage(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def findElementsByCss(self,selector):
        return self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)

    def visit(self,url):
        return self.driver.get(url)
```

Then other pages does not need to be aware of the driver but can just

```
class FrontPage(BasePage):

    def searchForItem(self,item)
        return findElementsByCss(".input").send_keys( "hey" )
```

So now its very simple to just visit the frontpage and search for an item. Is this correct thinking or have i confused it?

Answer (score 0):

Passing webdriver as argument of class constructor makes it more generic.
You can just:

```
firefox_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
firefox_browser = BasePage(firefox_driver)
chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome() (I hope that this method works)
chrome_browser = BasePage(chrome_driver)
```

You don't need to make two different classes for Firefox and Chrome.